# ERROR on E: EIdSocketError do begin - Delphi

Tags: delphi

[image]

I'm starting in Delphi , and creating a program to download ... In which I realize that when I try to download and type a wrong URL and it can not download ... Generates the error Error # 10060 Socket connection Time out ...
I know that this error is generated when it gets too long trying to make a connection to a URL that does not exist ....

```
E: EIdHTTPProtocolException
```

he Raises the number 0 (zero ) Error ... it does not exist in HTTP ...

I'm trying to prevent this error appears , it stops trying to access the page ... but I want the response to this error ... and cause it not to appear ....

I believe it is using: `on E: EIdSocketError the begin` ...

But the program generates error when I try to use : `undeclared undefined EIdSocketError`

How am by starting in delphi ... I do not know where I'm going wrong ... how to correct this error :

undeclared undefined EIdSocketError

> [ dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas ( 162 ) : E2003 Undeclared identifier: '
>   EIdSocketError '

```
except
         on E: EIdSocketError do begin

         end ;
         on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException the
             Begin
             / / Handle the error generated
               code_erro : = IdHTTP.ResponseCode ;
             / / code_erro : = E.ErrorCode ;
             end
        end ;
```

Comment: Add `IdStack` to your uses clause. You can find which unit you're missing if you grep your Indy library folder (I would consider this as a preferred way since the documentation doesn't have to match to your Indy version), or look into the [`EIdSocketError`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=EIdSocketError.html) class documentation. The unit you need to add you'll find under the `File` section. Btw. you can't embed images yet...

Comment: This error, and the resolution, is conceptually no different from the error you get when you refer to `TStringList` without using `Classes`. That's what E2003 undeclared identifier is all about. You should learn this lesson.

Comment: Please don't use JPG for non-photographic images, especially not for screenshots (of text!).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`EIdSocketError` is defined in the `IdStack` unit.  You need to add that unit to your `uses` clause.